# Show only hidden files (dot files) in ls alias

Tags: ls, alias, wildcards

I'm using the command

`ls -a | grep '^\.'`

for showing only the hidden files.
I added the line

`alias hidden='ls -a | grep '^\.'' # show only hidden files`

to `.bash_aliases` file

but this does not work. It's probably the problem with `'` character.

Could you please help me write the correct alias?

Comment: with examples that are even more complex, you very rarely have to switch from single- to double-quotes. This can be done just by butting the quotes up against one another. For this example, it would be `'ls -a | grep '"'"'^\.'"'"'` It looks awful (and for this example it is completely unnecessary because you can just swap out double-quotes for either of the pairs), but on very rare occasions it is useful. You might also want `-C` flag (force multi-column output). See this image http://imgur.com/a/VIVFP

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Either make the inner pair of quotes double quotes:

```
alias hidden='ls -a | grep "^\."'
```

Or make the outer pair of quotes double quotes:

```
alias hidden="ls -a | grep '^\.'"
```

Or make all quotes double quotes and escape the inner pair:

```
alias hidden="ls -a | grep \"^\.\""
```

Or make it a function, so you can pass some arguments when calling:

```
hidden() { ls -a "$@" | grep '^\.'; }
```

Answer (score 131):

Have the shell list the dot files, and tell `ls` not to see through directories:

```
ls -d .*
```

Comment: This has the advantage of allowing multi-column listing, unlike the `grep`-based approach.

Comment: However, shows also directories (as mentioned). Any way to keep it simple as is and show only files?

Comment: @honzajde The question didn't ask to exclude directories. If you want to exclude directories, you can use `ls -d .* | grep -v '^d'` or (zsh only) `print -lr .*(.)`

Comment: this not work for me, on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: This has the advantage of showing directories as well

Answer (score 12):

```
ls -Ad .* #This will list all the hidden files & directories while retaining the color & formatting
```

OR

To create an alias of the same:

```
alias lh='ls -Ad .*'
```

OR

Same thing could be done via grep command and pipe operator; however it would loose the color and formatting:

```
ls -a|grep "^\."
```

OR

Via alias:

```
alias lh='ls -a|grep "^\."'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use double quotes:

```
alias hidden="ls -a | grep '^\.'"
```

or concatenate more single quoted strings

```
alias hidden='ls -a | grep '\''^\.'\'
```

or remove at all internal quotes

```
alias hidden='ls -a | grep ^\\.'
```

Answer (score 2):

For the record this doesn't seem to work with me, since `ls -a` prints two (sometimes more columns). I would recommend using the `-1` option to make sure every file is in its own line. Something like this:

```
alias hidden='ls -a1 | grep "^\."'
```

Comment: I just tried `ls -a | cat` it still outputs on 2 columns. I should mention I'm using Solaris and not the GNU ls. Maybe that's why. In all cases your `-1` solution worked perfectly and is much more elegant than my hackish workaround. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: I probably missed this discussion, but look here if something will go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**First answer which shows an alias allowing to add a directory path as usual**

Try

```
alias lsh='ls -al --ignore="[^.]*"'
```

where ls ignores all files and directories which NOT start with a `.`

Or

```
alias lsh='ls -Al --ignore="[^.]*"'
```

to avoid `.` and `..` entries

Then just call

```
lsh /path/directory/
```

Answer (score 1):

Making it slightly more complicated, but avoiding [parsing `ls`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).

```
llsh () { find "${@:-.}/" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name ".*" -ls; }

lsh () { find "${@:-.}/" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name ".*" -print; }
```

The two shell function will use `find` to generate a list of all hidden regular files in the current directory, or in the directory given on the command line.

The `llsh` function will generate a "long listing" which will be only slightly more verbose than `ls -l`, while `lsh` generates a single-column listing like `ls -1`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function version of this instead of an alias. It does rely on extended glob, which can be turned on with `shopt -s extglob`. This allows for SHELL pattern matching, which in this implementation prevents `.` and `..` from being returned as entries.

```
hidden() {
    if [[ $# -eq 1 ]]; then
        exec 3>&1
        _hidden=$(cd "${1}"; ls -d .!(|.)?* 1>&3)
        unset _hidden
        exec 3>&-
    elif [[ $# -gt 1 ]]; then
        exec 3>&1
        for i in $@; do
            _hidden=$(cd "${i}"; echo "${i}:" 1>&3; ls -d .!(|.)* 1>&3)
        done
        unset _hidden i
        exec 3>&-
    else
        ls -d .!(|.)*
    fi
}
```

It `cd`s into the desired directory in a subshell, and redirects the output to the current shell. This stops the path of the provided directory being written preceding each entry. It should behave very similarly to `ls` when given directory arguments.

If you want to show `.` and `..`, just change the three `ls` commands in the function to `ls -d .*` which is also not dependant on extended glob. You can also add other arguments to this command, like `--color=auto`. The function itself will not accept these option arguments. If options are already included in an alias redefining `ls`, the function will use the alias and therefore implement those options.

Answer (score 0):

Does your `ls` support -A? From `man ls`:

```
    -a, --all
          do not ignore entries starting with .

   -A, --almost-all
          do not list implied . and ..

$ ls --version
ls (GNU coreutils) 8.5
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  
Written by Richard M. Stallman and David MacKenzie.
```

Comment: Yes, it does, but I wanted `only` hidden files.

Comment: `ls -A -1 -d -F .* | egrep -v '/$'`

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -name ".*"
```

OR

```
find . -type f -name ".*" | while read file; do basename $file; done
```

Comment: Hi! You could improve your answer by explaining in detail how it works, and also by mentioning why, in your opinion, it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
# add it to ~/.bashrc

    hidden() {  # lists hidden files and directories
        find . -maxdepth 1 -name '.?*' -exec ls --color -d {} \;
        }

    hiddenfiles() { # lists hidden files
        find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '.?*' -exec ls --color -d {} \;
        }

    hiddendirs() { # lists directories
        find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '.?*' -exec ls --color -d {} \;
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

Just simply type the below command and dont confuse with above explained stuff.

```
ls -A -1 -d -F .* | egrep -v '/$'
```

Comment: I think the OP asked for how to write an alias properly.

Comment: That's just a copy of waltinator's comment on his/her answer. For this answer to be useful, you need to explain how and why those particular `ls` flags and the `egrep` command answer the question.

Answer (score -3):

```
ls -lart | sed -n "/ \.[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*/p"
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer, one line of code is not counted as good answer

Comment: as per requirement he need to list only hidden files. so i have list all files including hidden files by ls -lart. then i have use regex to show that files which is start with dot(.) . I have got outpout like this.

Comment: [g906016@hklu2574881:[PTA] ~]$ ls -lart | sed -n "/ \.[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*/p"
-rw-r--r--   1 g906016 g906016    658 Dec 29  2016 .zshrc
-rw-r--r--   1 g906016 g906016    171 Dec 29  2016 .kshrc
-rw-------   1 g906016 g906016     27 Dec 29  2016 .k5login
-rw-r--r--   1 g906016 g906016    176 Dec 29  2016 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--   1 g906016 g906016     18 Dec 29  2016 .bash_logout
-rwxr-xr-x   1 g906016 g906016      0 Dec 29  2016 .dir_colors
drwxr-x---   3 g906016 g906016   4096 Dec 29  2016 .subversion