# List hidden files only (not just dot files) using an ls alias

Tags: shell, shell-script, osx, ls, bsd

I would like to use an `ls` alias (like `l.`) to output a colored list, consisting of only hidden files & directories, whether or not they begin with a dot.  Any suggestions?

**Example of desired results...**

```sh
## Listing all contents of $PWD
$ ls -AF
file                                directory/
.dot-file                           .dot-directory/
hidden-file                         hidden-directory/

## Listing all hidden contents of $PWD, using alias `l.`
$ l.
.dot-file                           .dot-directory/
hidden-file                         hidden-directory/
```

**Research...**

I've seen answers to similar questions.  These answers are awesome, but don't quite accomplish what I'm asking because:

- [They only display hidden dot files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21665/165656)

  - If I ran `chflags hidden file`, then `file` would be excluded from the `l.` output
- [They are confined to displaying the hidden dot files in `grep` style, as opposed to `ls` style](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21641/165656)

  - This is important because I may want to throw a flag like `-l` on there

#### DETAILS

```sh
## Current `ls` alias
alias ls="ls -h ${COLORFLAG}"
```

I use both `bash` & `zsh`.

Comment: This should probably be tagged "OS X" or "BSD" since "chflags" is OS X and BSD specific .

Comment: @jayhendren – Changed tags accordingly.  Although the `chflags hidden` bit was just an example, I appreciate the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will use the `find` command to retrieve dot files and files with the "hidden" flag set.

The matching files are fed as an argument list into `ls` via `sed` (to remove the "." result as well as leading "./" prefixes) and `xargs`. This allows for the specification of additional `ls` parameters (e.g. `-l`).

```
alias l.="find . \( -flags +hidden -or -name '.*' \) -maxdepth 1 | sed 's/^\.\/*//' | xargs ls -d"
```

The whole construct is designed to list the current directory only (`-maxdepth 1` parameter to `find`); if this is not desired, a conditional would need to be introduced to check for a `-R` option and suppress the `maxdepth` option to `find` accordingly.

Example:

```
$ ls -alO
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  9 guido  staff  -      306 Apr 13 22:43 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 6 guido  staff  -      204 Apr 13 19:00 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 guido  staff  -       68 Apr 13 22:43 .hiddendir
-rw-r--r--  1 guido  staff  -        0 Apr 13 21:48 .xx
-rw-r--r--  1 guido  staff  -        0 Apr 13 21:17 file
-rw-r--r--  1 guido  staff  -       18 Apr 13 21:03 file.b
drwxr-xr-x@ 2 guido  staff  hidden  68 Apr 13 22:43 hidden2
-rw-r--r--@ 1 guido  staff  hidden   0 Apr 13 22:35 hide
drwxr-xr-x  2 guido  staff  -       68 Apr 13 21:51 tst

$ l.
.hiddendir  .xx     hidden2     hide

$ l. -alO
drwxr-xr-x  2 guido  staff  -      68 Apr 13 22:43 .hiddendir
-rw-r--r--  1 guido  staff  -       0 Apr 13 21:48 .xx
drwxr-xr-x@ 2 guido  staff  hidden 68 Apr 13 22:43 hidden2
-rw-r--r--@ 1 guido  staff  hidden  0 Apr 13 22:35 hide
```